# Typo - For loop not working correctly with argument

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, for-loop

```
def game(digits):
    five_digit = ""
    for x in range(digits):
        five_digit = str(random.randint(0, 9))
        five_digit += five_digit
```

When I print `five_digit` I get the output of `22`, `88`, `55`, `33` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many problems:

- your variables and function are very poorly named; why does `game` return a string of digits? Why is the string called `five_digit` when it is an arbitrary number of digits?
- <s>your indentation is broken, both in your question and your solution.</s> *fixed now*
- repeated string concatenation is slow; `str.join` is a better method (pun intended)

Try instead

```
from string import digits
from random import choice

def digit_string(length):
    return "".join(choice(digits) for _ in range(length))
```

or maybe

```
from random import randint

def digit_string(length):
    return "{0:0{1}d}".format(randint(0, 10**length - 1), length)
```

Comment: I was trying to shorten my code and then when I introduced the arguments I had to keep changing the variable names and I just kept missing them and then when I copy and pasted the code in to my question my indentations messed up then I without checking I just posted, next time I'll be sure to check through my code thoroughly.

Comment: May I ask what should I call my function and variables?

Comment: @Navin: function and variable names should be the first level of documentation - they should indicate the *meaning* of how you are using them. You should be able to show your code to a complete stranger (ed: who is a competent programmer), and they should be able to figure out what it is doing. Obviously this is more art than science ;-/

Answer (score 1):

```
def game(digits):
    five_digit = ""
    for x in range(digits):
        digit = str(random.randint(0, 9))
        five_digit += digit
```

I know where I Went wrong, my for loop was overwriting `five_digit`.